# How do I handle a SignalR event from within an Angular service?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angularjs, signalr

I have an Angular app that has a service wrapping up SignalR interaction. I can send data to the server from both the page and within an Angular service but can only handle events from the page (events in the service never fire).

For some context, this is a test app for having video controls in a different window to the video that is playing.

**SignalR Hub code**

```
public class VideoHub : Hub
{
    public void SetPlaybackStatus(string status)
    {
        Clients.All.statusChanged(status);
    }
}
```

**Angular Controller**

```
commsTest.controller("videoController", [
    '$scope', 'signalRService',
    function ($scope, signalRService) {

        $scope.playbackStatus = "No Status";

        signalRService.onStatusChanged(function (status) {
            console.log("Callback status", status);
            $scope.playbackStatus = status;
        });
    }
]);
```

**SignalR Angular Service**

```
commsTest.service('signalRService', [
    '$', function ($) {

        var proxy,
            initialized = false,
            statusChangeCallbacks = [];

        var initialize = function (callback) {

            // Get the connection object
            var connection = $.hubConnection();

            // Create proxy
            proxy = connection.createHubProxy('videoHub');

            // Start connection
            connection.start().done(function () {
                initialized = true;
                console.log("Connected");
                callback();
            });

            // This bit here never fires
            proxy.on('statusChanged', function (status) {
                console.log("Caught from service.", status);
                callStatusChangedCallbacks(status);
            });
        };

        var setPlaybackStatus = function (status) {
            if (!initialized) {
                initialize(function() {
                    setPlaybackStatus(status);
                });
            } else {
                // This bit works as expected
                proxy.invoke('setPlaybackStatus', status);
            }
        };

        var onStatusChanged = function (callback) {
            if (callback) {
                statusChangeCallbacks.push(callback);
            }
        };

        function callStatusChangedCallbacks(status) {
            for (var i = statusChangeCallbacks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                statusChangeCallbacks[i](status);
            }
        }

        return {
            onStatusChanged: onStatusChanged,
            setPlaybackStatus: setPlaybackStatus
        };
    }
]);
```

The event handler (marked above) never fires within the service. I have this code directly on the page:

```
$(function() {
    // Gett the connection object
    var connection = $.hubConnection();

    // Create proxy
    var proxy = connection.createHubProxy('videoHub');

    // Start connection
    connection.start();

    // This gets called as expected
    proxy.on('statusChanged', function (status) {
        console.log("Caught in page.", status);
    });
})
```

This fires as expected when the server code emits the update.

I've also tried using the direct methods on the JS side instead of a proxy but I get the same result.

i.e.

```
var videoHub = $.connection.videoHub;
videoHub.client.statusChanged = function (status) {
    console.log("Callback within service");
    callStatusChangedCallbacks(status);
};
```

Is there something going on with the encapsulation of the objects within Angular that stops the JS in there picking up the event?

Just for completion's sake, I'm passing in jQuery as such:

```
var commsTest = angular.module('commsTest', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

    // Routes stuff
}]);

commsTest.value('$', $);
```

Any suggestions very much welcome.

Comment: Works on me. Here is my [.cshtml with JS code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bspjdcbgakk52m6/Test.cshtml). Some modifications: 1. moved the `proxy.on` before `connection.start` 2. use `$log` instead of `console`

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your problem using angular 1.2.12, SignalR 2.0 (using your code without changes)

Comment: @LostInComputer - Thanks! Moving the `proxy.on` before `connection.start` fixed it. To be honest, I'm not sure why that would make a difference but just glad to see this event firing at long last!

Comment: If you want you can have a look at my library called SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy, its designed with SPA in mind. https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy